# macOS App Switcher, transparency and Dark Mode?

Tags: macos, application-switcher, dark-mode

I recently switched to macOS Mojave Dark Mode, and I like many aspects of it.

But there's one thing that really gives me trouble, i.e., using the App Switcher in front of a window that is mainly dark/black.

When I use the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to invoke the App Switcher, the switcher *highlights* the *currently selected* app using a black frame. Black frames do not work too well when they are used transparently above black background.

I did then turned to the Accessibility settings to *Reduce transparency* but that actually made things worse.

Is there a way to somehow fix this problem?

(I installed [HyperSwitch](https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch) as a workaround. The UI part works much better there for me, but the actual logic of app switching is "wrong" when using multiple screens, so that renders it a no go for me)

Two screenshots are shown below. The first one shows the App Switcher with the first app (iTerm) selected.

[image: iterm-selected]

In the second one, now the selection is on Google Chrome (which one can somehow guess from the fact, that the app name is highlighted below the icon).

[image: chrome-selected]

Comment: seems like a dark-mode bug. In non-dark-mode the translucent tray behind the apps stays light enough the ui element stays visible.

Comment: You can give the couple apps mentioned in [this](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/unlock-the-full-power-of-the-macos-app-switcher/) blog post a try. Free trials are available. However, they change the UI for the App Switcher.

Comment: For such a design oriented company I can't believe this still isn't fixed. Getting close to 2 years without being able to tell which app is current in the dark mode app switcher.

Comment: @teradyl Very true. But at least that inspired me to write a short "self answer" though ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the last comment indicates, 2 years later, still no official solution by Apple.

My personal answer: invest the 10 Euros/USDs for the [Contexts](https://contexts.co/) switcher. That product works fine for my requirements. It appeared to be dead, but after months of no activity, a new version was released March 2021.